# The method newBuilder() is undefined for the type ResourceNotFoundDetails.Builder

Tags: java, spring-boot

Saudações Pessoal,

Estou com um problema na minha API ao tentar realizar a tratativa de erros, Segue código:

```
package com.guilhermeoscp.apisistemaescolar.handler;

@ControllerAdvice
public class RestExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleResourceNotFoundException(ResourceNotFoundException rfnException) {
        ResourceNotFoundDetails rnfDetails = ResourceNotFoundDetails.Builder
                .newBuilder()
                .timestamp(new Date().getTime())
                .status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value())
                .title("Resource not Found")
                .detail(rfnException.getMessage())
                .developerMessage(rfnException.getClass().getName())
                .build();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(rnfDetails, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);      
    }

}
```

Na linha onde tem **.newBuilder()** está com erro informando pela seguinte mensagem "The method newBuilder() is undefined for the type ResourceNotFoundDetails.Builder". Já tentei fazer a instanciação do tipo **ResourceNotFoundDetails** com a variável **rnfDetails** para ver se era o problema, organizei cada parâmetro em uma linha para ficar mais visível e fácil de identificar o erro, coloquei as variáveis , timestamp, status, title, detail, developerMessage e build dentro do *newBuilder* mas também falhou. Não tenho mais ideias do que fazer, segue classe **ResourceNotFoundDetails**:

```
package com.guilhermeoscp.apisistemaescolar.error;

public class ResourceNotFoundDetails {
    private String title;
    private int status;
    private String detail;
    private long timestamp;
    private String developerMessage;

    private ResourceNotFoundDetails() {
    }
    
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public String getDetail() {
        return detail;
    }

    public long getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public String getDeveloperMessage() {
        return developerMessage;
    }
    
    @Generated("SparkTools")
    private ResourceNotFoundDetails(Builder builder) {
        this.title = builder.title;
        this.status = builder.status;
        this.detail = builder.detail;
        this.timestamp = builder.timestamp;
        this.developerMessage = builder.developerMessage;
    }
    
    @Generated("SparkTools")
    public static Builder newBuilder() {
        return new Builder();
    }

    @Generated("SparkTools")
    public static final class Builder {
        private String title;
        private int status;
        private String detail;
        private long timestamp;
        private String developerMessage;

        private Builder() {
        }

        public Builder title(String title) {
            this.title = title;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder status(int status) {
            this.status = status;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder detail(String detail) {
            this.detail = detail;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder timestamp(long timestamp) {
            this.timestamp = timestamp;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder developerMessage(String developerMessage) {
            this.developerMessage = developerMessage;
            return this;
        }

        public ResourceNotFoundDetails builder() {
            return new ResourceNotFoundDetails(this);
        }
    }   
}
```

Ainda não consegui entender porque o método **newBuilder** é indefinido para o **ResourceNotFoundDetails.Builder** sendo que fiz a instanciação do mesmo na classe **ResourceNotFoundDetails** para ter gerado esse erro. Alguém tem alguma ideia do que seja? Agradeço a ajuda desde já.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver o problema para deixar minha mensagem padronizada para o tipo de erro "Resource Not Found". O construtor **builder** na minha classe **ResourceNotFoundDetails** estava assim:

```
public ResourceNotFoundDetails builder() {
     return new ResourceNotFoundDetails(this);
}
```

Ele estava retornando a ele mesmo, mas sem os parâmetros que eu utilizei na classe **RestExceptionHandler** para fazer o corpo da mensagem padrão. Então alimentei o construtor **builder** com todas as variáveis do corpo da minha mensagem assim:

```
        public ResourceNotFoundDetails builder() {
            ResourceNotFoundDetails resourceNotFoundDetails = new ResourceNotFoundDetails();
            resourceNotFoundDetails.developerMessage = this.developerMessage;
            resourceNotFoundDetails.title = this.title;
            resourceNotFoundDetails.detail = this.detail;
            resourceNotFoundDetails.timestamp = this.timestamp;
            resourceNotFoundDetails.status = this.status;
            return resourceNotFoundDetails;
        }
```

Após eu alterar o construtor meu código parou de apresentar erro e ao testar funcionou perfeitamente. Problema resolvido! :)